# using JSON for logic jquery

Tags: jquery, json

This is part two of my problem here. Thanks to you guys I was able to get variables to work correctly to split data out to a jSON string. Now, I need to filter the JSON data to get a result.

For example:
if the JSON file gets this data:

```
 {"shapeID":"diamond","data1":"pants","data2":"shirt"} it outputs:

  {"result":"Cool Outfit"}
```

so depending on the combination of data1 and data2 the result is generated.

I have no idea on where to start. But I do have the JSON string

thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, what rules do you want to use? What leads to the conclusion that diamond+pants+shirt = Cool outfit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (data.data1 == "pants" && data.data2 == "shirt"){
    return { result: "Cool Outfit" };
}
```

Comment: how would I chain this? for multiple options?

Comment: With that && 

just add more if statements

Comment: i meant if (data.data1 == "pants" && data.data2 == "shirt"){
    return { result: "Cool Outfit" };
}else{
if (data.data1 == "pants" && data.data2 == "shirt"){
    return { result: "Cool Outfit" };
} do I just keep on saying else?

Answer (score 1):

That's going to depend on your logic to use. From the example posted, I can't derive the relationship from your input to your output. However, the general format will be like so:

```
 var myObj = yourJsonParser.ParseJson(someText);

 if(myObj.shapeId == "diamond")
    return { result: "Cool Outfit" };
```

You're returning a new object with data in a JSON-like format.